# dependencies in the requirements.txt file were not installed

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, airflow, requirements.txt

I am developing a dag in Airflow. I am trying to install dependencies by using requirements.txt file.
I run the container in my dev(Windows 11) environment, but dependencies are not installed. I am getting the below error message in Airflow UI:

```
    Broken DAG: [/opt/airflow/dags/my_dag.py] Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
      File "/opt/airflow/dags/my_dag.py", line 6, in <module>
        import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib'
```

I rebuild the docker image by using below commands but it did not work.

```
    docker-compose down
    docker-compose build
    docker-compose up -d
```

Requirements.txt file is as below:

```
    pandas
    scikit-learn
    sqlalchemy
    airflow
    dbt
    matplotlib
```

Dockerfile is as below:

```
    # Use an official Airflow image as the base image
    FROM apache/airflow:2.7.3

    # Set the working directory to /usr/src/app
    WORKDIR /usr/src/app

    # Copy the requirements.txt file into the container at /usr/src/app
    COPY requirements.txt .

    RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

    # Install any needed packages specified in requirements.txt
    #RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r ./requirements.txt

    # Make port 8080 available to the world outside this container
    EXPOSE 8080
```

I am expecting to import the below Python libraries in my_dag.py. However, I can not install matplotlib or scikit-learn into the container worker nodes

```
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
    from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
    from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
```

Comment: What directory is `requirements.txt` kept in

Comment: It is under the project folder. requirements.txt, docker-compose.yaml and Dockerfile are in the same directory, on the same level

How can I check whether the below command executed?
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt </br>